# Why is the shell executing an alias instead of a function?

Tags: bash, function, shell, alias

I've added some alias in `.bashrc` as shortcuts for git commands.
One example is `ga` for `git add`

But when I made some changes to the `ga` function like:

```
function ga() {
  echo "hello"
}
```

And use `ga` in the terminal, it is still using `git add`.
I tried to comment out `ga` by editing .bashrc, and then using `source ~/.bashrc`. However, it still executes the alias instead of the function.

What would be the cause?

Comment: do you have a `ga` alias? what's the output of `type ga`?

Comment: `Nothing specified, nothing added. Maybe you wanted to say 'git add .'?`

It's the same as using `git add`.
It is still using the old function, not the new one with `echo`

Comment: you've completely altered the question and the reported fault.  What you are doing exactly isn't clear.  I'll remove my answer, please give the exact steps that lead to the fault occuring

Comment: When I did an EDIT, I was just trying different possible solution, but I'm still doing the same thing. I want to make a function / shortcut for git commands. The exact steps are, I've defined my functions / shortcuts in `~/.bashrc`. Then source it in `~/.bash_profile`. And when I'm doing some changes, those changes doesn't reflect even if I source both `~/.bash_profile` or `~/bashrc`. Though I have fixed the problem by using `unalias`, I still don't know what caused the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define an alias you have to take into account that they are looked up *before* functions:

```
$ alias hello="echo 'this is a hello alias'"
$ function hello() { echo "this is a hello function"; }
$ hello
this is a hello alias
#               ^^^^^  <--- it executes the alias, not the function!
```

So what's the way to call the function? **Just use `\`  before its name**. It will bypass the alias:

```
$ \hello
this is a hello function
#               ^^^^^^^^  <--- it executes the function now
```

You can also use `unalias`, so the alias is removed.

```
$ unalias hello
$ hello
this is a hello function
#               ^^^^^^^^
```

And what if the alias and the function have the name of a command? Then it comes handy using [`command`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/command):

```
$ alias date="echo 'this is an alias on date'"
$ function date() { echo "this is a function on date"; }
$ date
this is an alias on date
#          ^^^^^              <--- it executes the alias, not the function!
$ \date
this is a function on date
#         ^^^^^^^^            <--- it executes the function
$ command date
Thu Jan 21 10:56:20 CET 2021
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   <--- it executes the command
```

You can also use [`nice`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nice):

```
$ nice -n0 date
Thu Jan 21 10:56:20 CET 2021
```

As seen in [Aliases vs functions vs scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4024/40596):

> Aliases are looked up *before* functions: if you have both a function and an alias called `foo`, `foo` invokes the alias. (If the alias `foo` is being expanded, it's temporarily blocked, which makes things like `alias ls='ls --color'` work. Also, you can bypass an alias at any time by running `\foo`.) I wouldn't expect to see a measurable performance difference though.

Further reading:

- [GNU Bash on Aliases](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases) (*For almost every purpose, shell functions are preferred over aliases*, they say)
- [In Bash, when to alias, when to script, and when to write a function?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30950/40596)

Comment: And of course, in your specific case you need to unalias. Otherwise, the current aliases will be still available.

Comment: I see, this is what I've been looking for. Thank you for the explanation and source materials.

Comment: it was interesting to go through different sources and provide a general answer, since your problem has funny insights. Glad it helped you!

Answer (score 1):

I've found an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325368/how-do-i-remove-an-alias).
I used `unalias` to remove the aliasing of `ga`

```
unalias ga

ga() {
  echo "ZAWARUDO"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to delete the old definitions. The easiest way would be to just open a new interactive bash shell. Instead of sourcing `.bashrc`, simply do a

```
bash
```

Of course this means that functions/aliases/non-exported variables, which you had **manually** definied in your current shell, also get lost.

Comment: What should I do inside the interactive bash shell?
Sorry, I'm dumb with shell scripting.

Comment: I've edited the question, please take a look again.

Comment: @CRIS : You are not doing **any** shell scripting in your example! Actually, .bashrc would be the wrong place for definitions needed in shell scripting anyway. After changing something in .bashrc, simply enter `bash` in your console (i.e. the letterns `b` `a` `s` `h`), and hit the enter key. You get a fresh instance (as a child process of the previous one), and hence your updated definitions.

Comment: @CRIS : If you dislike the idea of getting a sub-shell here, you could probably (I did not test it) do a `exec bash` instead. This would replace your current bash process by a new one.

Comment: ahh, I thought I have to redefine my functions when I do the interactive bash.

Though, I prefer the your second suggestion. Both this one and the one I've found (using unalias) worked. Thanks!